# script filter field value is in array

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Here is a part of my query:

```
 must_not: {
    script: {
      script: {
        source: "doc['type.keyword'].value=='CHANNEL' ? doc['id'].value == 0 : doc['id'].value.contains(['1','3','7'])",
        lang: 'painless'
      }
    }
  }
```

**How can I check if `doc['id'].value` has a value from an array?**

I've tried different ways:

```
source:"doc['type.keyword'].value=='CHANNEL' ? doc['id'].value == 0 : params.ids.values.contains(doc['id'].value)",
 params: {
   ids: [5,6]
}

source:"doc['type.keyword'].value=='CHANNEL' ? doc['id'].value == 0 : params.ids.contains(doc['id'].value)",
 params: {
   ids: ['5','6']
}

source:"doc['type.keyword'].value=='CHANNEL' ? doc['id'].value == 0 : for (el in params.ids) {doc['id'].value==el}",
 params: {
   ids: ['5','6']
} . ERROR
```

The only way is working is without an array, but not helping me:

```
source:"doc['type.keyword'].value=='CHANNEL' ? doc['id'].value == 0 : doc['id'].value==params.ids",
 params: {
   ids: 5
}
```

**The complete query:**

```
searchStr = 'a string' //dynamic
types = ['CHANNEL', 'AUDIO', 'ALBUM', 'MOVIE'] .  ///dynamic array of strings
searchAllTypes = ['CHANNEL', 'AUDIO', 'ALBUM', 'MOVIE']
excludedContent = [1, 5, 6, 8] - //a dynamic array
genres = 'aString' //dynamic
tag = 3 //dynamic
       query:
       {
         bool: {
           should:
           [
               //1.here is a function I use, but I added the entire code so it can be read better
               return types.map(type => {
             type === 'CHANNEL' ? excludedContentIds = [] : excludedContentIds = excludedContents; //2.this is my workaround -
   the line I want to get rid of
             return {
               bool: {
                 must: [
                   { match: { 'type': type } }, //3.if I get rid of line (2) I would use filter - terms - all types here. 
                   //But trying to use terms in combination with 'execution='OR'' is not working inside filters anymore, but inside
   query  
                   { match: { 'discoverable': true } },
                   { match: { 'status': 'PUBLISHED' } },
                   { match: { 'category.name': genres } },
                   { match: { 'tag.id': tag } },
                   {
                     multi_match: {
                       query: searchStr,
                       type: 'phrase_prefix',
                       slop: 5,
                       fields: config.elasticSearch.search.fields,
                       operator: 'AND',
                     }
                   }
                 ],
                 //// must_not workaround now, because I'm filtering excludedContentIds for CHANNEL in the function above (2)
                 must_not: [
                   { terms: { 'id': excludedContentIds } }
                 ]
               }
             };
           });
             ]
         }
       },
       aggs: {
         'by_top_first': {
           terms: {
             field: 'type.keyword',
               size: searchAllTypes.length,
             },
           aggs: {
             'by_top_hit': { top_hits: { size: 1 } },
             'max_score': { max: { script: '_score' } },
           }
         }
       },
       {
         'by_type': {
           terms: {
             field: 'type.keyword',
               size: searchAllTypes.length
           },
           aggs: {
             'by_top_hit': { top_hits: { size: limitSize ? limitSize : 6 } },
             'max_score': { max: { script: '_score' } },
           }
         }
       }
```

Comment: Curious to know why script is required? This can be done by `term` and `terms` query. Are you using the the above code snippet for scoring/sorting etc?

Comment: Nishant Saini, I'll post the complete query above so you can see why I cannot use a different way. In the end, I've found a workaround outside the query, tough I'm not happy with it

Comment: Besides the problem I've raised, How could I use fuzziness for my `searchString`? in combination with `phrase_prefix`? Or is there any other way so the search would hint results starting with the first letter wrote, other than `phrase_prefix` functionality? I mean once the user is start writing `t` as a string I want all results starting with `t` to appear and also to gave them the possibility to introduce mistakes `tset` instead of `test`.

Comment: You can't - `The fuzziness parameter cannot be used with the phrase or phrase_prefix type.` [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase). In this situation I would try to simplify the query, remove all workarounds and build it up from there.

Comment: Looking at you query you want documents that should match your `phrase query AND "discoverable": true AND "status": "PUBLISHED" AND "category.name": "aString" AND "tag.id": 3 AND ("type": "CHANNEL" OR ("type": "AUDIO" "ids" NOT IN [1, 5, 6, 8]) OR ("type": "ALBUM" "ids" NOT IN [1, 5, 6, 8])  OR ("type": "ALBUM" "ids" NOT IN [1, 5, 6, 8]))` . Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: yes, You're correct

Comment: For now, is working with types filtered outside query. I was just curious how can I handle the query exactly as you typed above without being forced to filter outside

Comment: Furthermore, I've found the solution with fuzziness and phrase_prefix working together. `minimum_should_match` is the solution :) . I've replaced `{
                     multi_match: {
                       query: searchStr,
                       type: 'phrase_prefix',
                       slop: 5,
                       fields: config.elasticSearch.search.fields,
                       operator: 'AND',
                     }
                   }`        with

Comment: { bool: {should: [{bool: {must: [{multi_match: {
 query: searchStr,
fuzziness: 'auto',
prefix_length: 3,
fields: ..,operator:'OR'} }
            ]  }
        }, {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                multi_match: {
                  query: searchStr,
                  type: 'phrase_prefix',
                  slop: 5,
                  fields: ..,operator: 'OR'}}]}}],
      minimum_should_match: 1}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare the array value as a script parameter and then use it in your script to test if it contains a value:

```
must_not: {
  script: {
    script: {
      source: "doc['type.keyword'].value=='CHANNEL' ? doc['id'].value == 0 : params.ids.contains(doc['id'].value)",
      params: {
        ids: ['1','3','7']
      },
      lang: 'painless'
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, see the [Painless docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-filter-context.html)

Comment: but it's not working :(, I've tried different sintaxes:

Comment: Strange... I've tried it on ES 6.3 and it worked fine. It should be syntactically correct. What's the error message?

Comment: no error message, indeed, just not filtering the right way